# "Складываются" ли медиа-запросы?

Tags: css, css3, media-queries

Допустим, есть `div` с классом `container` и CSS код:

```
.containert {
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .container {
    width: 300px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .container {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

Предположим, что разрешение экрана пользователя - 450x450. Так вот, будут ли работать оба медиа-запроса? То есть, будет ли ширина и высота div`a равняться 300px?

P.S. Понимаю, что объяснение не самое лучшее. Простите, я тупой.

Comment: Да, сработают оба. Можете проверить в браузере.

Comment: первый раз вижу запрос на высоту :D чего только не увидишь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Складываются, но если ввести в медиа запрос (max-width) width:300px; , а в медиа запрос (max-height) width: 301px то при одинаковых условиях , сработает тот стиль который был написан ниже в документе